# Error using OpenCV for Connected Components on numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to do a connected component analysis on an image using OpenCV in python. The images are in a '.czi' format so I am using aicsimageio to import the file into numpy array. However, I keep receiving the error:

> OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\connectedcomponents.cpp:5632: error: (-215:Assertion failed) iDepth == CV_8U || iDepth == CV_8S in function 'cv::connectedComponents_sub1'

Below is some code similar to what I am trying to do. I will just create an numpy array for simplicity (instead of importing the image).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

test = np.random.rand(512,512)
(T, thresh) = cv2.threshold(test, 0.5, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
num_labels, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(thresh)
```

This returns the error described above on the final line of code. The error seems to be something to do with the fact that the image wasn't imported using OpenCV, as I have got the same code to work when importing a random '.jpg' using OpenCV. I'm not sure why, since importing the '.jpg' using OpenCV returns a numpy array, i.e.:

```
image = cv2.imread(file)
type(thresh) == type(image)
```

returns True

Any help on how to fix this would be much appreciated!

Comment: `type(thresh)` should be `numpy.ndarray`. But the array has elements of specific type. You can see that with `thresh.dtype`. The threshold function expects an 8-bit integer type.

Comment: Ahh yes thank you! I converted the values in the array to unit8 and that fixed it